# Python, scrapy: pdf to text conversion: no error while running code, but don't seem to be generating any output

Tags: python, scrapy, pdftotext

I am quite a newbie to python, scrapy and web scraping, so my question might seem naive. Apologies for that upfront.

I want to extract data from a pdf file, using scrapy. There are several questions on stackoverflow on this subject which I looked up and copied following code from one of the answers given. However, I am unable to see any output. Used print function in the code directly to see the output, tried writing the return value to an excel file, but that also is not showing any output. Am not getting any error either.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 2
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    strval = retstr.getvalue()
    print strval
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return strval
```

Can anyone guide me where am I going wrong?

Thanks!
Tuhina

Comment: I do not see any Scrapy-code here. Are you sure your method is called from your Scrapy-code? (Hint: if you add a `print path` as the first line in `convert_pdf_to_txt` do you get the path as output?)

Comment: @GHajba : I have tried to print path at the start and it gives correct path value. I have put the above code in a separate file named pdfscraper.py. I have another file with a spider defined in it. In the spider's parse function, I am calling covert_pdf_to_txt function [after importing it at the beginning of the file]. I am not sure if this is even the right way to go about it. Perhaps I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: If the path is printed to the console the method is called. Did you try to debug the code process -- putting print statements after some of the statements to see what your code reach and where it stops? alternatively did you try to `print retstr.getvalue()` inside of the `for` loop after processing the page to see the result of each iteration?

Comment: @GHajba: Added print stmt at various points including just before return stmt, all get printed, so we are going through entire code. However, <br/> print retstr.getvalue() <br/> doesn't print anything :(

Comment: Does it print something inside the `for` loop? Because it can happen that at the end the `retstr` is empty -- this is why you do not get a result but inside the loop it is filled sometimes.

Comment: nope..nothing getting printed inside for loop. This is how I am trying it out: for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
  interpreter.process_page(page)
  print retstr.getvalue()

Comment: In this case I guess it has something in the interpreting of the PDF if you get multiple empty lines on the console. If there is no empty line then perhaps the for loop is not executed at all.

Comment: Empty lines being printed. Thanks for the direction - i'll try to look deeper into interpreting part of this code.

Comment: If you find the solution please add it as your answer to this question. Thanks.